# allow modifying django model fields to certain users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a marketplace REST Api on DRF where there are Creators and Brands. Creators can publish their projects and brands can make offers. I have an AbstractUser class and

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_creator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_brand = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

class Creator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Brand(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

projects-related models look like follows:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, )
    description = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Creator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class ProjectOffer(models.Model):
    PENDING, NEGOTIATIONS, APPROVED, DECLINED = range(4)
    STATUS = (
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (NEGOTIATIONS, 'Negotiations'),
        (APPROVED, 'Approved'),
        (DECLINED, 'Declined'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name='project_offers',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project_offers',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS,
                                              default=PENDING)
```

The issue is the following. The project offer is made by the brand. It is linked to a project. The brand should have the opportunity to update its offer, say title or description. But they cannot update the status, as it is updated by the creator. And vice versa, the creator cannot update title and description fields.

How can I achieve this logic? For my ProjectOffer view I am using ModelViewSet from DRF

I know there might be 2 ways:

1. through permissions (but don't really know how to implement)
2. through serializers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello sir, you can use the User.is_creator and User.is_brand to know the type of the user of request in your viewsets (api, depending what the name you prefer) and create 2 different projects serializers, one for creators and another for the brand

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. That might be the option. But I wonder if there is a solution through permissions though